# How to share a YouTube video with a specific start and end time on AMP?

Tags: youtube, amp-html

How to share a YouTube video with a specific start and end time on Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)?

Comment: you want to show or share? 

You can use start and end parameter like https://www.youtube.com/embed/YvuJtlMDja0?start=50&end=70

Comment: The method is not valid because the video in pages  AMP, works like this :
`<amp-youtube width="480"
  height="270"
  layout="responsive"
  data-videoid="lBTCB7yLs8Y">
</amp-youtube>`

Comment: Use amp-iframe in place of amp- youtube to achieve your goal

Comment: @BachchaSingh
the YouTube video does not work if you put it inside iframe,This is a test model : http://jsfiddle.net/ngqg603u/

Comment: check my answer, hope this help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `amp-iframe` may not appear close to the top of the document. The iframe must be either 600 px away from the top or not within the first 75% of the viewport when scrolled to the top, whichever is smaller. For work on top we have to use `placeholder` attribute

[**Here is working URL**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0xvhs88/)

[FOR MORE INFORMATION](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe#iframe-with-placeholder)

Comment: @Asfar if this answer help you, please accept this, so that other community member also get help from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a start time by passing the `start=<number of seconds from beginning>` as `data-param-start=<number of seconds from beginning>` data parameter on the `amp-youtube` tag. Similar for the end time.

See the `Attributes` section in the docs - https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-youtube/?format=websites